# Alfresco 5 wf content model

Tags: workflow, alfresco

Where is the wf content model definition file in Alfresco Community 5?
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Best regards

Mattia Parise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.0.a.jar. The main two XML files related to workflow are:

- alfresco/model/bpmModel.xml
- alfresco/workflow/workflowModel.xml

Prior to Alfresco 5 these files resided in the classpath rather than being part of the JAR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jeff. I cannot find any doc about deploying again that .jar file after making some modifies. Could you please give me that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You should not be making any changes to any of the files in that JAR. Instead, create your own content model and tell Alfresco about it through Spring configuration. If you don't know how to do that, see http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html. If you need help with custom workflows, see http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html.